# MediaElement freezes video

Tags: c#, wpf

I apply some `LinearGradientBrush` animation to `MediaElement` and after this video is freezing.

I try to reset it via `Player1.OpacityMask = null;` but no joy.

By the way if I animate `Opacity` of the `MediaElement` then video shows good as usually.

Any clue what's up? How to fix the video freezing after applying `LinearGradientBrush` animation to `MediaElement` ?

Thank you!

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for WipeTransition.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class WipeTransition
    {
        public WipeDirections Direction { set; get; }

        public TimeSpan Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

        public bool StopPrevPlayerOnAnimationStarts;

        Random rdm = new Random(1);


        bool isPlayer1;

        public WipeTransition()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            try
            {
                Loaded += WipeTransition_Loaded;
                SizeChanged += WipeTransition_SizeChanged;

                Player1.CacheMode = new BitmapCache();
                Player1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;

                Player2.CacheMode = new BitmapCache();
                Player2.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;

                Direction = WipeDirections.RandomDirection;

                Player1.Width = ActualWidth;
                Player2.Width = ActualWidth;

                Player1.Height = ActualHeight;
                Player2.Height = ActualHeight;

                isPlayer1 = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        void WipeTransition_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Player1.Width = ActualWidth;
            Player2.Width = ActualWidth;

            Player1.Height = ActualHeight;
            Player2.Height = ActualHeight;
        }

        void WipeTransition_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Player1.Width = ActualWidth;
            Player2.Width = ActualWidth;

            Player1.Height = ActualHeight;
            Player2.Height = ActualHeight;
        }

        public void Start(Uri uri)
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("************** START ANIMATION ***************************************");

                Player1.Width = ActualWidth;
                Player2.Width = ActualWidth;

                Player1.Height = ActualHeight;
                Player2.Height = ActualHeight;

                // We start to Animate one of the Player is on BACK

                if (isPlayer1)
                {
                    if (StopPrevPlayerOnAnimationStarts)
                        Player2.Stop();

                    Canvas.SetZIndex(Player2, 49);

                    Canvas.SetZIndex(Player1, 50);

                    Player1.Source = uri;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Player1 - ANIMATE");

                    WipeAnimation(Player1);
                }
                else // Player2
                {
                    if (StopPrevPlayerOnAnimationStarts)
                        Player1.Stop();

                    Canvas.SetZIndex(Player1, 49);

                    Canvas.SetZIndex(Player2, 50);

                    Player2.Source = uri;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Player2 - ANIMATE");

                    WipeAnimation(Player2);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        public void WipeAnimation(FrameworkElement ObjectToAnimate)
        {
            try
            {
                LinearGradientBrush OpacityBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();

                #region Setup Wipe Direction
                switch (Direction)
                {
                    case WipeDirections.RightToLeft:
                        OpacityBrush.StartPoint = new Point(1, 0);
                        OpacityBrush.EndPoint = new Point(0, 0);
                        break;
                    case WipeDirections.LeftToRight:
                        OpacityBrush.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
                        OpacityBrush.EndPoint = new Point(1, 0);
                        break;
                    case WipeDirections.BottomToTop:
                        OpacityBrush.StartPoint = new Point(0, 1);
                        OpacityBrush.EndPoint = new Point(0, 0);
                        break;
                    case WipeDirections.TopToBottom:
                        OpacityBrush.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
                        OpacityBrush.EndPoint = new Point(0, 1);
                        break;
                    case WipeDirections.RandomDirection:
                        #region
                        int randomValue = rdm.Next(0, 3);

                        if (randomValue == 0)
                        {
                            OpacityBrush.StartPoint = new Point(1, 0);
                            OpacityBrush.EndPoint = new Point(0, 0);
                        }
                        else if (randomValue == 1)
                        {
                            OpacityBrush.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
                            OpacityBrush.EndPoint = new Point(0, 1);
                        }
                        else if (randomValue == 2)
                        {
                            OpacityBrush.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
                            OpacityBrush.EndPoint = new Point(1, 0);
                        }
                        else if (randomValue == 3)
                        {
                            OpacityBrush.StartPoint = new Point(0, 1);
                            OpacityBrush.EndPoint = new Point(0, 0);
                        }

                        #endregion
                        break;
                }

                #endregion

                GradientStop BlackStop = new GradientStop(Colors.Black, 0);
                GradientStop TransparentStop = new GradientStop(Colors.Transparent, 0);

                if (FindName("TransparentStop") != null)
                    UnregisterName("TransparentStop");
                RegisterName("TransparentStop", TransparentStop);

                if (FindName("BlackStop") != null)
                    UnregisterName("BlackStop");
                this.RegisterName("BlackStop", BlackStop);

                OpacityBrush.GradientStops.Add(BlackStop);
                OpacityBrush.GradientStops.Add(TransparentStop);
                ObjectToAnimate.OpacityMask = OpacityBrush;

                Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
                DoubleAnimation DA = new DoubleAnimation() { From = 0, To = 1, Duration = Duration };
                DoubleAnimation DA2 = new DoubleAnimation() { From = 0, To = 1, Duration = Duration };
                sb.Children.Add(DA); sb.Children.Add(DA2);
                Storyboard.SetTargetName(DA, "TransparentStop");
                Storyboard.SetTargetName(DA2, "BlackStop");
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(DA, new PropertyPath("Offset"));
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(DA2, new PropertyPath("Offset"));

                sb.Duration = Duration;
                sb.Completed += sb_Completed;

                sb.Begin(this);

                if (isPlayer1)
                {
                    Player1.Play();
                }
                else // Player2
                {
                    Player2.Play();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        void sb_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isPlayer1)
            {
                Player1.OpacityMask = null;
                isPlayer1 = false;
                Player2.Stop();
                Player2.Source = null;
            }
            else // Player2
            {
                Player2.OpacityMask = null;
                isPlayer1 = true;
                Player1.Stop();
                Player1.Source = null;
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("************** END ANIMATION ***************************************");
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            if (Player1.IsEnabled)
                Player1.Stop();

            if (Player2.IsEnabled)
                Player2.Stop();
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

The same problem happens after I apply **[shader](http://wpffx.codeplex.com/)** effect. So video goes well before it and after this it is jumping/freezing. It seems that we have somehow to reset `MedieElement` or?

```
 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TransitionEffect[] effectGroup = transitionEffects[1];
            TransitionEffect effect = effectGroup[1];

            DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation(0.0, 1.0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0)), FillBehavior.HoldEnd);
            da.AccelerationRatio = 0.5;
            da.DecelerationRatio = 0.5;
            da.Completed += da_Completed;
            effect.BeginAnimation(TransitionEffect.ProgressProperty, da);

            VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush(this.Player1);
            vb.Viewbox = new Rect(0, 0, this.Player1.ActualWidth, this.Player1.ActualHeight);
            vb.ViewboxUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;

            effect.OldImage = vb;
            this.Player1.Effect = effect;
        }
```