# Transparent Background Color in Video Clip

Tags: c#, wpf, video, transparency, opacity

I would like to play a video clip within my WPF application, and make the green color in the video transparent.

How can this be done ?

Sample Video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XJVkAOEjp0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use shaders as explained in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200851/green-screen-in-wpf/5224629#5224629).

WPF Pixel Shader library won't compile out of the box, you will need to make some changes as explained [here](http://wpffx.codeplex.com/discussions/73720), in the post before last.