# c# xaml run video transparent

Tags: wpf, video, transparent

I have project in C# in xaml. I need play video with transparent background. 
The transparent background is green. [For example show on this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8cnrLKLDY0)

[I used this project](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/How-to-Use-Media-Element-b8ce7e92)

Thanks for answer ZUF

Comment: An approach is described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200851/green-screen-in-wpf/5224629#5224629